# Need a hint for a proof using the pumping lemma that a language is not regular

Tags: regular-language, proof-explanation, pumping-lemma

Currently I am stuck at a proof of :

$A_2=\{w001;|w|_0<|w|_1 \wedge w\in \sum^*\}$

unsing only the pumping lemma. Can you give me a hint for a good start?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Try $w=0^p1^{p+1}$. In fact, you can alo try $w=1^p$ (why?)

Comment: It looks like home work, especially since you already asked a similar question less than an hour ago. What did you try?

Comment: why can I use 1^p+1?

Comment: What is that mean $|w|_0<|w|_1$?

Comment: @Nehorai Your guess is right (according to your answer) and it is a standard notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Assuming that $|w|_0<|w|_1$ means that the number of one's $>$ number of zero's

> $$A_2=\{w001;|w|_0<|w|_1 \wedge w\in \small\sum^{\quad *}  \}$$

Let us choose the word $z=1^p$ so $1^p001\in A_2$

**Spoiler:**

> $\quad|z|>p$ So $z=uvw,\quad |uv|\leq p, \quad |v| \geq 1, \quad uv^iw\in \mathcal L \quad i\geq0$  For  $i=0$ the word not in $\mathcal L$ because the number of one's$=$number of zero's